# arranging dictionary elements in sorted order

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

In my scinario, I am having data as kind of a sorted list:

```
  sample =  ['1:4', '2:2', '3:1', '4:1', '5:1', 'B5S94Y:1', 'DB:4', 'ICEauthority:1', 'JPG:1', 'MZPZ5Y:1', 'Mdg80A:1', 'TAG:1', 'V2XO5Y:1', 'Xauthority:1', 'apmrc:1', 'asc:1', 'bak:1', 'baseA:4', 'baseB:4', 'bash:1', 'bash_history:1', 'bash_logout:1', 'bashrc:1', 'bat:1', 'bau:1', 'bdic:1', 'bin:5', 'c:282', 'cache-6:55', 'cache:103', 'cfg:3', 'conf:15', 'converted-launchers:1', 'cson:2', 'css:34', 'dat:2', 'db-journal:3', 'db-shm:1', 'db-wal:1', 'db:17', 'dbf:1', 'dbt:1', 'deb:3', 'desktop:2', 'dic:1', 'dirs:1', 'dll:42', 'dmrc:1', 'docx:9', 'exc:1', 'exe:20', 'final:1', 'fingerprint:4', 'fmt:1', 'gif:5', 'gitconfig:1', 'gitignore:6', 'gitkeep:2', 'gitmodules:1', 'gpg-agent:1', 'gpg:1', 'gradle:3', 'gvdb:1', 'gz:169', 'h:14', 'htm:1', 'html:43', 'icc:1', 'ico:1', 'ics:3', 'idx:5', 'info:1', 'ini:14', 'ino:1', 'isrunning:1', 'jar:1', 'java:7', 'journal:2', 'jpg:16', 'js-20170612122310:1', 'js-20170816210634:1', 'js:245', 'json:367', 'jsonlz4:39', 'kbx:1', 'keyring:1', 'keystore:1', 'ldb:23', 'list:2', 'little:2', 'locale:1', 'localstorage-journal:71', 'localstorage:71', 'lock:1', 'log:41', 'lst:2', 'lsup7I:1', 'lz4:1', 'm:1', 'map:2', 'md:92', 'md~:1', 'metadata-v2:6', 'metadata:6', 'mozlz4:2', 'name:1', 'nls:1', 'odb:2', 'odt:1', 'old:24', 'orig:1', 'otf:31', 'out:19', 'pack:5', 'pak:1', 'parentlock:2', 'pb:32', 'pdf:18', 'pf2:5', 'php:12', 'pl:1', 'pma:2', 'png:2348', 'pro:1', 'profile:1', 'properties:2', 'pset:42', 'pub:1', 'py:41', 'pyc:4', 'rb:1', 'rcache:2', 'rdf:2', 'reg:3', 'run:1', 'sample:72', 'sbstore:42', 'sdv:1', 'sh:27', 'so:2', 'source:1', 'spec:9', 'sqlite-journal:1', 'sqlite-shm:4', 'sqlite-wal:4', 'sqlite3-journal:1', 'sqlite3:1', 'sqlite:24', 'stamp:2', 'stderr:8', 'stdout:8', 'sth:19', 'sublime_session:1', 'sudo_as_admin_successful:1', 'svg:124', 'swo:1', 'swp:2', 'sys:1', 'tdb:3', 'thm:1', 'trashinfo:3', 'tsv:1', 'ttf:107', 'tvc:1', 'txt:63', 'update-timestamp:1', 'usage:6', 'viminfo:1', 'vxd:1', 'woff:1', 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu:1', 'xba:1', 'xbel:1', 'xcu:1', 'xinputrc:1', 'xlb:2', 'xlc:2', 'xml:35', 'xpi:9', 'xsession-errors:1', 'yml:1', 'zcompdump:1', 'zip:5', 'zsh-template:1', 'zsh-theme:143', 'zsh-update:1', 'zsh:235', 'zsh_history:1', 'zshrc:1']
```

So after converting this above list to a dictionary with the following code:

```
dict_val = {a:b for a, b in [i.split(":") for i in sample]}
```

The output will be:

```
{'baseA': '4', 'baseB': '4', 'cache-6': '55', 'Xauthority': '1', 'gitmodules': '1', 'apmrc': '1', 'gz': '169', 'dbf': '1', 'kbx': '1', 'sqlite-shm': '4', 'dbt': '1', 'gitignore': '6', 'xml': '35', 'sbstore': '42', 'cache': '103', 'jar': '1', 'desktop': '2', 'source': '1', 'sqlite3-journal': '1', 'TAG': '1', '4': '1', 'tsv': '1', 'spec': '9', 'bin': '5', 'docx': '9', 'woff': '1', 'db': '17', 'V2XO5Y': '1', 'dat': '2', 'fingerprint': '4', 'lz4': '1', 'name': '1', 'bat': '1', 'bau': '1', 'converted-launchers': '1', 'h': '14', 'list': '2', 'lst': '2', 'gradle': '3', 'zsh-update': '1', 'mozlz4': '2', 'stderr': '8', 'sublime_session': '1', 'bak': '1', 'isrunning': '1', 'locale': '1', 'cfg': '3', 'htm': '1', 'odt': '1', 'xlb': '2', 'md~': '1', 'pma': '2', 'sqlite-journal': '1', 'odb': '2', 'dic': '1', 'tvc': '1', 'out': '19', 'ico': '1', 'icc': '1', 'dll': '42', '3': '1', 'rb': '1', 'ics': '3', 'py': '41', 'journal': '2', 'metadata': '6', 'dirs': '1', 'run': '1', 'tdb': '3', 'DB': '4', 'zshrc': '1', 'xpi': '9', 'pub': '1', 'js': '245', 'asc': '1', 'ldb': '23', 'xlc': '2', 'xbel': '1', 'properties': '2', 'bash': '1', 'sys': '1', 'c': '282', 'zip': '5', 'idx': '5', 'lsup7I': '1', 'zcompdump': '1', 'rdf': '2', 'dmrc': '1', 'Mdg80A': '1', 'pdf': '18', 'reg': '3', 'jsonlz4': '39', 'bashrc': '1', 'db-journal': '3', 'pf2': '5', 'localstorage': '71', 'old': '24', 'txt': '63', 'orig': '1', 'gvdb': '1', 'little': '2', 'pyc': '4', 'java': '7', 'log': '41', 'swo': '1', 'stamp': '2', 'vxd': '1', 'fmt': '1', 'gpg': '1', 'zsh-template': '1', 'pb': '32', 'gif': '5', 'json': '367', '2': '2', 'js-20170612122310': '1', 'swp': '2', 'bash_logout': '1', 'final': '1', 'pl': '1', 'gpg-agent': '1', 'sdv': '1', 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu': '1', 'parentlock': '2', 'cson': '2', 'rcache': '2', 'otf': '31', 'usage': '6', 'bash_history': '1', 'localstorage-journal': '71', 'update-timestamp': '1', 'png': '2348', 'exc': '1', 'info': '1', 'md': '92', 'js-20170816210634': '1', 'sth': '19', 'yml': '1', 'sqlite-wal': '4', 'deb': '3', 'zsh': '235', 'pack': '5', 'zsh_history': '1', 'sqlite': '24', 'stdout': '8', 'lock': '1', 'pro': '1', 'gitkeep': '2', 'jpg': '16', 'sample': '72', 'ino': '1', 'pset': '42', 'ini': '14', 'conf': '15', 'xcu': '1', 'sudo_as_admin_successful': '1', 'xsession-errors': '1', 'keystore': '1', 'nls': '1', 'sh': '27', 'bdic': '1', '1': '4', 'html': '43', '5': '1', 'MZPZ5Y': '1', 'sqlite3': '1', 'pak': '1', 'ttf': '107', 'css': '34', 'profile': '1', 'map': '2', 'metadata-v2': '6', 'm': '1', 'zsh-theme': '143', 'trashinfo': '3', 'ICEauthority': '1', 'php': '12', 'B5S94Y': '1', 'viminfo': '1', 'exe': '20', 'db-shm': '1', 'xinputrc': '1', 'svg': '124', 'keyring': '1', 'JPG': '1', 'thm': '1', 'gitconfig': '1', 'so': '2', 'xba': '1', 'db-wal': '1'}
```

So I want to know why the order of the output data has changed compared to the input data and how to get the output in the same sorted order as the input is given!!

Comment: Python dictionaries are (currently) unordered. In future versions, this may change (but remain a detail of implementation rather than a part of the API): see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6) for example.

Comment: If you want to preserve the order, you should probably use an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Use an OrderedDict https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Why the elements are not arranged in the order the inputs are given???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict`s in python versions older than 3.6 do not have any notion of ordering. If you want a dictionary that maintains order, you'll want the `collections.OrderedDict` data structure.

```
from collections import OrderedDict    
mapping = OrderedDict(i.split(":") for i in sample)
```

`mapping` is an `OrderedDict`, a *subclass* of `dict` which supports all the basic `dict` functionality, plus the ordering.

Also, do not use `dict` as a variable name, it shadows the builtin class `dict`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED : But while adding elements into dictionary why they got reagganged??

Comment: @Sjn73 Read: `dicts in python versions older than 3.6 do not have any notion of ordering.` It's also mentioned in the documentation, if you read it.